# Connecting to Conference over node-xmpp on Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-xmpp

How to connect to a Jabber conference? Send and receive messages. Get a list of online users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did some testing from `localhost` using prosody.im. I had two clients:

- `alfred1`: Just normally XMPP client
- `alfred2`: My bot

I created MUC `alfred@conference.localhost`.

When I first connect to channel from XMPP client(`alfred1`) and next run the bot, I receive test message from bot(`alfred2`). And I will also receive chat message from `alfred1` in console when I sent message from XMPP-client.

```
var xmpp = require('node-xmpp'),
        sys = require('sys'),
        jid = 'alfred2@localhost',
        password = '1234',
        room_jid = 'alfred@conference.localhost',
        room_nick = 'alfred2',
        conn = new xmpp.Client({
        jid         : jid,
        password    : password,
        });

conn.on('online', function () {
  console.log('online');
    //var elm2 = new xmpp.Element('presence', { from: jid, to: 'alfred@conference.localhost'}).c('x', {'xmlns': 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc' }).up();

    conn.send(new xmpp.Element('presence', { to: room_jid +'/' + room_nick }).
    c('x', { xmlns: 'http://jabber.org/protocol/muc' })
  );

  conn.send(new xmpp.Element('message', { to: room_jid, type: 'groupchat' }).
    c('body').t('test')
  );
});

conn.on('stanza', function(stanza) {
    sys.puts(stanza);
});

conn.on('error', function(e) {
    sys.puts(e);
});
```

Maybe later I try to improve code a bit, but I guess this gets you going...

---

**From jabber.org:**

> but as always feel free to join the
>   jabber@conference.jabber.org chatroom
>   via XMPP or HTTP if you have questions
>   or comments.

You mean connecting to jabber@conference.jabber.org?

I believe that should look up [MUC](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) specifications for that. I think it is possible using  only node-xmpp, but node-xmpp is pretty low-level library. I used [npmjs.org's search](http://search.npmjs.org) to look for modules supporting MUC, but could not get any of them working yet.. I think MetaJack's [source-code about MUC](https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp/blob/master/ch08/groupie.js) could help you out. This could be a fun project to implement over the weekend I guess.

When you like to get started immediately you should probably(maybe somebody has MUC in node-xmpp?) have a look at [Smack(Java)](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html) for example which does support MUC.

Comment: specifications
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#register

node.js example
http://pastebin.com/FdWHYTq9

but no result, the user is not logged into the chat =(

Comment: To be honest I am also not an expert on that.. Hopefully somebody else can help you better...

Comment: I also found this snippet on github and now am able to jjoin room :) => https://gist.github.com/940969

Comment: updated answer a little bit. I believe I can sent messages, receive messaages. I also get notified when presence changes.